# MySQL: Need to run a calculation based on user input and data on another table

Tags: mysql

I am trying to make a "Savings Calulator" where we take user input and compare it to a real world simulator of an energy saving appliance.

I have two tables, one where the user inputs into the table "MainEntry":

- State
- # of Occupants
- Heating Fuel Type
- Setpoint Temp.

The calculation I am having it run is to sum a column "dTw" on another table "DataComp" when the values in column "Tmedw" fall between "Setpoint" & "ColdWaterIn". 
This is the script I wrote:

```
SUM(CASE 
    WHEN DataComp.Tmedw>34.95 
    and DataComp.Tmedw<57.22 
    THEN (DataComp.dTw)/3600 END) AS Tw,
```

I would like the query to run that calculation, and then return the value to a field in the user entry table "MainEntry".

I have made this calculator in Excel, using the "SUMIFS" command, but don't know what the equivalent is in MySQL. Searching hasn't really helped the problem.

I have made an imgur album [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WoGiP.jpg) that helps explain my issue. I am pretty new to MySQL, and maybe I'm going about this problem incorrectly, but I feel like this issue should be easy to solve.

Thanks.

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: It looks like you are treating MySQL as spreadsheet, which it most certainly is not. You either have to run a batch script of some kind outside of MySQL that does that calc for each row and updates the table, or include the calculation in your sql select at run time. You may be able to use calculated fields also to do that.